# How do I print notification after executing a line in a function in Python

Tags: python, function

I have a long function and wanted to know if there is a way to print a notification after each step of the function is run successfully. Here is an example of what the function looks like -

```
def multiple_regression(df):
    
    #Step 1
     some code
     some code

     #Step 2
      some code
      some code

      #Step 3
       some code

       return output
```

when call run the function and pass a dataframe, the output will be -

```
"Performing step 1..."

"Performing step 2..."

"Performing step 3..."

 output
```

However say I run the function and there is an error in step 2, the output would be -

```
"Performing step 1..."

"Error in step2! Check step 2"
```

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: As an unrelated detail I suggest you wrap each step in its own function.

Comment: And give a meaningful name to each step

Answer (score 2):

Basically add `print("NOTIFICATION")` after code.

---

Use `try..catch`??

```
try:
  some code
except:
  print("MAN Test failed")
```

---

For unit testing, This is basics. use `unittest` module and `assert` statements [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add some print statements under your lines of code. So you see which step has an error.

```
#code
print('step1')
#code
print('step2')
#code
print('step3')
#code
print('step4')
```

You can print after every line of code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping each part of the code inside your function with a `try`-`except` statement like so:

```
try:

    #code step 1
    print('success')    #or any other type of notification you want

except theErrorYouwantToCatch:

    print('error')     #or any other error message you want
```

and repeating that process for all the code "steps" you want to get notified about.

Answer (score 0):

you can use try except statements with prints to give the desired output although I wouldn't recommend it because this is not its purpose and would make an unclean code. it's rather pointless since the traceback gives the exact location of the error. here you are.

```
def multiple_regression(df):
    
    #Step 1
    try:
        print('Performing step 1')
        some code
        some code
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception('Error in step 1')

    #Step 2
    try:
        print('Performing step 2')
        some code
        some code
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception('Error in step 2')
       #Step 3
    try:
        print('Performing step 3')
        some code
        some code
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception('Error in step 3')

        return output
```